# camel read directory and choose a destination by completion task result

Tags: csv, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-data-jpa

I need to read a directory with csv files (one or more files). I use Camel with springboot and I need to move any file processed completely(without errors) to OUT dir, but if the last "to" route fails (an Exceptions is thrown) I need to move the file to REFUSED dir.

When I try my code, camel goes to infinitive loop, continue to process the same file forever..

```
24/08/2017 16:27:57.070 ERROR [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - file://src/main/resources/data] - org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler: Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-CAD1652-39380-1503584865077-0-33 on ExchangeId: ID-CAD1652-39380-1503584865077-0-34). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: com.cadit.exceptions.FileNotEvaluableException: Error: file tipo sconosciuto

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route2            ] [route2            ] [file://src/main/resources/data?idempotent=false&move=OUT%2FVB%2F              ] [        10]
[route2            ] [unmarshal1        ] [unmarshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.CsvDataFormat@28f6cf0f]           ] [         1]
[route2            ] [to1               ] [bean:myCsvHandler?method=doHandleCsvDataVB                                    ] [         8]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.cadit.exceptions.FileNotEvaluableException: Error: file tipo sconosciuto
    at com.cadit.handlers.MyCsvHandler.doHandleCsvDataVB(MyCsvHandler.java:172)
    at com.cadit.handlers.MyCsvHandler$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f4b8f70b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at com.cadit.handlers.MyCsvHandler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d81d9e7f.doHandleCsvDataVB(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:458)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:289)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:262)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:178)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProducer.process(BeanProducer.java:41)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:460)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:227)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the main code:

```
@Component
public class CamelContextConf extends RouteBuilder{

     static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CamelContextConf.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().component("servlet").dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true") ;
                    CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();
        csv.setDelimiter(";");  
        csv.setSkipHeaderRecord(true);


        from("direct:csvprocessor")
        .streamCaching()
        .from("file:src/main/resources/data?move=OUT/VB/")
        .unmarshal(csv) 
        .to("bean:myCsvHandler?method=doHandleCsvDataVB")
        .onCompletion().onFailureOnly().to("file:src/main/reources/data/REFUSED").end()
        .setBody(constant("OK"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200))
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("text/html"));

        logger.info("** Route config ok");

    }
```

then in myCsvHandler -> method doHandleCsvDataVB I explicitly throw an exception for testing
a failure :

```
@Component
public class MyCsvHandler {


    @Inject
    AFVINCCrudRepository _entityManagerVINC;

    @Inject
    AFFileCrudRepository _entityManagerAfFile;

        @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED , transactionManager="DbTransactionManagerVB")
    public void doHandleCsvDataVB(List<List<String>> csvData) throws FileNotEvaluableException
    {
        //System.out.println("stampo..");
            if (csvData.size() > 0){
            AfFileEntity afbean = new AfFileEntity();
            afbean.setNomeFile("test");
            afbean.setDataImport(new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            afbean.setTipoFile("M");
            afbean.setAfStatoFlusso("I");

            _entityManagerAfFile.save(afbean);

            long pkfile = afbean.getId();
            System.out.println("pkfile: " + pkfile);

            int i = 1; VincEntity vincBean = new VincEntity(); 
            System.out.println(csvData.size());
            for (List<String> rows : csvData){

                ..  
                    _entityManagerVINC.save(..);
                }   

                    throw new FileNotEvaluableException("Il file non è nè una ...");

            }

        }

    }

}
```

The save methods loop and continue to save data on db..
What's wrong?

Thanks so much.

Comment: .from("file:src/main/resources/data?move=OUT/VB/&moveFailed=REFUSED") ??

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you cannot have from inside another from.

```
from("direct:csvprocessor")
.streamCaching()
.from("file:src/main/resources/data?move=OUT/VB/")
```

Your second  `from("file:...")` should instead use an enricher. http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html

Not sure, but in your `doHandleCsvDataVB()` method I don't see a `try() catch()` block. You are going straight from a for loop to throwing the exception.

Comment: enrich is only for producer, pollEnricher polling one files at a time? ..but i have to poll all files in that director,y not only one at time..

Comment: Can you explain at a high level what the purpose of the flow is is? What functionality do you want to acheieve? Receive a REST request and then proceed to poll all the files from an ftp folder?

Answer (score 0):

I did the below way to move the file from one folder to another folder.

```
@Autowired
FileProcessor fileProcessor;

@Component
public class FileRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file://{{dir.in}}?readLock=changed&include=.*.csv"&preMove={{dir.progress}}&move={{dir.out}}&moveFailed={{dir.error}}")
                    .process(fileProcessor).setId("Poller");
    }
}
```

- dir.in -Source directory for file polling
- dir.progress -File will be moved from in to progress for processing
- dir.out -File will be moved here when processed successfully
- dir.error - File moved here when any error occur during process
- readLock=changed - this will lock the file while reading
- include - this will read only csv files in source dir i.e in folder

you may or may not have processor as per your needs.
if you don't want processor then use below code

```
from("file://{{dir.in}}?readLock=changed&include=.*.csv"&preMove={{dir.progress}}&move={{dir.out}}&moveFailed={{dir.error}}")
                        .setId("Poller");
```

Please note that, if you are not using preMove then default .camel folder will be created in the 'in' folder and one copy of file moved to .camel folder. file will always exist in the directory until and unless we remove manually.

So i suggest you to use the preMove in the route.